# Oracle SQL Developer - renaming attributes causes errors

Tags: sql, oracle, attributes, oracle-sqldeveloper, rename

I'm having a weird situation going on in Oracle SQL Developer. I had to rename some attributes to match my school's variable names standards and when I am executing the program, the new attribute names doesn't seem to have been taken into account.

For example, I'm creating a table named VARIANT like this :

```
create table VARIANT(
  ID_VAR varchar(9) not null,
  NUCL_VAR char(1) not null,
  NUCL_REF_VAR char(1) not null,
  CHROMOSOME_VAR number(2) not null,
  GENE_VAR varchar(5) not null,
  POSITION_VAR number(4) not null,
  EFFET_VAR varchar(100) not null,
  INDEX_EFF_VAR number(2, 2) not null,
  URL_DRUGBANK_VAR varchar(500) not null,

  constraint PK_VARIANT primary key(ID_VAR),
  constraint FK_URL_DRUGBANK_VAR foreign key(URL_DRUGBANK_VAR)
    references DRUG(URL_DRUGBANK_DRO),
  constraint DOM_INDEX_EFF_VAR check(INDEX_EFF_VAR > 0)
);
```

My problem occurs when I execute the table creation request. The output in SQLDev's console doesn't match my code :

```
create table VARIANT(
  ID_VAR varchar(9) not null,
  NUCL_VAR char(1) not null,
  NUCL_REF_VAR char(1) not null,
  CHROMOSOME_VAR number(2) not null,
  GENE_VAR varchar(5) not null,
  POSITION_VAR number(4) not null,
  EFFET_VAR varchar(100) not null,
  INDEX_EFF_VAR number(2, 2) not null,
  URL_DRUGBANK_VAR varchar(500) not null,
  constraint PK_VARIANT primary key(ID_VAR),
  constraint FK_URL_DRUGBANK_VAR foreign key(URL_DRUGBANK_VAR)
    references DROGUE(URL_DRUGBANK_DRO),
  constraint DOM_INDEX_EFF check(INDEX_EFF > 0)
)

Error report -
00904. 00000 -  "INDEX_EFF: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

As you can see, in my code, the attribute INDEX_EFF is renamed INDEX_EFF_VAR in the constraint below but the change does not seem to have taken effect in the console's output for the constraint, even though the attribute name has been changed properly.

If someone could help me figure out what is going on here, that would be appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:

Found my way out of it. Seems that rebooting SQL Developer fixed the issue. But still, I'd like to know if there is another way of fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

As we can clearly see in the output, there is no such column name "INDEX_EFF". There might be some kind of user error here, you may try rerunning the SQL after clearing the console output to avoid any confusions.

Please note, you may try the options like drop and recreate table. If you don't want to loose the existing data, then follow these steps

- Drop the constraints
- Rename the column
- then finally add the constraint

Hope this helps you, though i can't say what actually gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key name is also wrong, check the key names.

Answer (score 0):

INDEX_EFF should be INDEX_EFF_VAR